# Office add-in for Outlook - Attaching a .msg file results in a file size of 0

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Office add-in for Outlook.

Currently, I am using the following method to get the size of the attached file while composing an email.

If I attach a msg file using the following procedure, I get an object with an attachment size of 0.

[getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview#getAttachmentsAsync_options__callback_)

Procedure

1. [New Email] > [Attach File] > [Browse This PC]
2. Select the msg file.
3. Call getAttachmentsAsync().

Example of the object retrieved when test.msg is attached in the above procedure.

```
{id: "0", name: "test", size: 0, attachmentType: "item", isInline: false}
```

Note that this only happens in the PC version of Outlook, not in Outlook on the web.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue. After careful consideration, our team has decided to not fix this issue in the short term. We recommend you to upvote or create a new [user-voice item](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins), this will give us visibility of the commonality of it and will help with our prioritization. If we end up working on this issue we will re-activate as needed.